# Booting failing in different Debian and Debian derivated distros?

Tags: kernel, boot

I've tried Ubuntu, Linux Mint and Debian, even though all have worked great for me I'm keeping with Ubuntu, I tested 12.04, 12.10 and even 13.04. The 12.04 LTS is the one I work with.

There's one issue persisting in the three distros I've tested, sometimes at *random* occasions the boot fails, after GRUB, it shows only a `_` as prompt and it remains indefinitely, I've let pass up to an hour, and best I could do was to wait for a while and try again until I get it to load.

Everytime this happens and I've selected **recovery mode** I get logs like these:

[image: Once I got this output] 
[image]

So, I blame the last line:

> **[ 0. .... ]Booting Node 0, Processors #1**

to be the *issue*, all first log lines appear continuously but it'll stop then.

I already updated BIOS, but there's something I think it might be the *issue* and that's the Hyperthreading, I had disabled it after BIOS update and it stopped happening, now I enabled it for installing a 64 bits OS in VMWare Player and it happened again.

I googled and I've not really found a solution.

Comment: Seems a known [problem][1], related to a BIOS incompatibility, apparently updating it did the trick.


  [1]: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1706348

Comment: As I commented in my question, I already updated BIOS and got not results so far ...

Comment: Have you update tp that version?

Comment: What do you mean?

Answer (score 1):

add nosmp option to kernel in your grub

Comment: Can you explain what that would be for? To be honest with the most recent kernels I got rid of the problem.